# modifying ajax returned data before showing

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I'm processing subscription form with jQuery/ajax and need to display results with success function (they are different depending on if email exists in database). But the trick is I do not need h2 and first "p" tag.

How can I show only div#alertmsg and second "p" tag?

I've tried removing unnecessary elements with method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878118/manipulating-the-data-from-ajax-success-functiondata/1878123), but it didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
var dataString = $('#subscribe').serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/templates/willrock/pommo/user/process.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data){
    var result = $(data);
    $('#success').append(result);
}
```

Here is the data returned:

```
<h2>Subscription Review</h2>

<p><a href="url" onClick="history.back(); return false;">
<img src="/templates/willrock/pommo/themes/shared/images/icons/back.png" alt="back icon"
     class="navimage" /> Back to Subscription Form</a></p>

<div id="alertmsg" class="error">

<ul>
<li>Email address already exists. Duplicates are not allowed.</li>
</ul>

</div>

<p><a href="login.php">Update your records</a></p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the context part of the `$()` operator, like this:

```
var dataString = $('#subscribe').serialize();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/templates/willrock/pommo/user/process.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data){
      var result = $(data);           
      $("h2, p:first", result).remove();
      $('#success').append(result);
    }
});
```

This looks for `<h2>` and the first `<p>` from the response and removes them before appending.  The default context (element to look under) is `document`, so when you're calling `$("h2")` you're *actually* calling `$("h2", document)` (which is actually calling `$(document).find("h2")`)...you can put something non-default there as well, in this case, the response.