# String to DOM to String

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, dom

I get some markdown text from a database. I am using Showdown.js to transform this markdown into HTML:

```
var showdown = new Showdown.converter();
var str = showdown.makeHtml(myDatabaseString);
```

When there is code embedded within the markdown, Showdown.js will wrap it nicely into `<pre><code>` tags, so `str` may look something like this:

```
<p>Some text bla</p><pre><code>Some code</pre></code><p>Text again</p>
```

Now I want make things prettier by syntax highlighting the code pieces using [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/). It's important that in the end I get a string back that contains everything it had before, plus the additional HTML for formatting.

My approach to this was the JQuery's ability to manipulate DOM:

```
$(str).each(function() {
    // or can I select only pre within $(str) directly?
    // everything I tried so far to do that failed miserably
    if($(this).is('pre')) {
        var code = $('code', $(this)).text();
        // brush is my SyntaxHighlighter brush that I created earlier
        $('code', $(this)).text(brush.getHtml(code));
        // when I console.log($('code', $(this))) now, everything worked
        // out perfectly
    }
});
// but now I lost all my changes for some reason :-(

return str; // I need to return this as a string again
```

Am I on the right way? How can I keep the changes I make within my `.each` loop?

Comment: You may find my answer here relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878118/manipulating-the-data-from-ajax-success-functiondata/1878227#1878227

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are creating a jQuery object that has nothing to do with `str` variable, you should use the created jQuery object. In fact you are modifying the elements of the created jQuery object and returning the original/unchanged `str` variable.  I'd suggest:

```
// Creating a wrapper element 
// and setting it's content by using str variable
var $wrapper = $('<div/>').html(str);

// Modifying descendant pre elements
$wrapper.find('pre').each(function(){
   // implementing the logic
});

// Getting modified HTML content of the created wrapper element
str = $wrapper.html();
```

Comment: You're the hero of the day.