# How to show the view of method in controller when data passed from ajax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing MVC application.

I want pass the values from View to controller.

I have use ajax to pass the values from View to controller.

Now this data goes perfectly into method....

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    $('#CheckOrder').click(function(){ 
      PassData();
    });

   function PassData()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ShowWHOrder", "Order")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { OrderNo: @ViewBag.OrderNo, OrderTo : '@ViewBag.OrderTo' }

  });

    }

});
```

Here is the method... in below method all parameters comes properly.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowWHOrder(string OrderNo, string OrderTo)
    {
        ViewBag.OrderNo = OrderNo;
        ViewBag.OrderTo = OrderTo;


        return View();
    }
```

Now, I have added the new view for this method.
But It doesn't redirect to new view, it remains on previous view only. 
Is due to ajax ? 
What option I have to show the new view ? 
How can I implement this without ajax ?

Comment: You should try using the success part of the `$.ajax` response and fill your current view with the information passed back via your ajax method.  The whole point of ajax is to be able to partially load information on the current page and not have to reload and take you to an entirely newly loaded page.

Comment: Though I have written the code, I dont think its right idea to use ajax here to show the new view...is there any alternative  ?

Comment: Why would you use ajax to redirect to a completely different view and why do you think it's not the right idea?  If you were going to just redirect them to a different view than you could just use regular anchor tags within MVC to direct the user to the new view with the information being passed.

Comment: ya, but I haven't used that so far... do you have any sample ?

Comment: Just search for $.ajax success as there are plenty of examples via the web.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878118/manipulating-the-data-from-ajax-success-functiondata.  That is just one quick one I found.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply...I want replacement of ajax.... How can I call the method by passing arguments without calling ajax ? is there any other way... ? I can pass it like this  ?   `var url2 = "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("UploadDocument", "PaymentAdvice", new { paymentAdviceId = "idValue" }))";` can you tell me how to use it in JScript ?

Comment: do you have a view named ShowWHOrder?

Comment: no , I dont have but how to call it from view, I dont want to use ajax for it... what other options I have to call the controllers method from view ?